# Adjust Font size by moving slide bar in android

Tags: android

How to design the screen in android in which the user can control the font size by moving slide bar like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmHcg.png

Comment: what have you done so far show some code

Comment: I am new to android and no idea from where to start?

Comment: Haha, we can't show you the whole project. You need to work on your basics mate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go...

1. Go to your activity_main.xml. Add 3 textview's as per your requirement. Add one seekbar. Go with below code so you can understand.

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Adjust font size"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       android:id="@+id/textView" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Adjust font size by moving slide bar"
       android:textSize="18dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       android:id="@+id/textView2" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/changeFont"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="This is preview of font-size"
       android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

   <SeekBar
       android:id="@+id/seekBar"
       android:layout_width="254dp"
       android:layout_height="44dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changeFont"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.137" />
   ```

   2. Go to your MainActivity.java. Define your textview and seek bar. Add change listener for seek bar. Set text size value dynamically for your textview. Please see below code for your reference.

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   TextView view;
   SeekBar bar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.changeFont);
       bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

       bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
               view.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(i));
           }

           @Override
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }

[See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdpbU.gif)

Let me know, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for your response.

Comment: One problem is seekbar is from 0 to 100 normally I want the font size in range 10 to 30.

Comment: In SeekBar you can set only max value.
To set max value, go to activity_main.xml, Under seekbar tag, add below line..

android:max="30"

If this answer resolved your issue, please vote for the answer.

Comment: Yes I tried to vote but gives me you have less than 15 reputation you cannot vote now,

Comment: @Anees Hi, if your issue has been resolved can you accept the answer? You have to click on right symbol under the vote indicators. Just click it.